# Can't convert from void to model While trying to put objects in array using <list>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to put all of the objects in a list, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Projects startupboost = new Projects(
            "startupboost",
            "StartUp Boost",
            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
            "WordPress, Custum built WP plugins, AJAX, PHP, MYSQL, JAVASCRIPT, jQUERY, SASS",
            "http://startupboost.dk/");

        List<Projects> pro = new List<Projects>()
        {
            pro.Add(startupboost)
        };


        return View();
    }
```

This is a method on the controller - the constructor is working without a problem and the object itself is working but I get an error on the line with `pro.Add(startupboost)` saying: `Can't convert from void to "my created model with class"`

Comment: Remove the brackets around `List<Projects>` declaration - it is unnecessary. Just do `List<Projects> pro = new List<Projects>(); pro.Add(startupboost);`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thank you very much!

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto prevent answering questions in comments

Answer (score 3):

You are now mixing up two ways of creating a collection. Use the collection initializer to create a new list with a specified item.

```
List<Projects> pro = new List<Projects>()
{
    startupboost
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Aars93's answer, you can also call `.Add` outside of the collection initializer:

```
List<Projects> pro = new List<Projects>();
pro.Add(startupboost);
```

Which will first create a new list and then add the `startupboost` to it.